# How to move from sliding window of accelerometer data to feature vector in gesture recognition task?

Tags: machine-learning, gesture-recognition, sliding-window

We have an application that needs to be able to recognize a short hand gesture based on the accelerometer data.

Now, I read lots of different papers on the subject (among which "Machine Learning Methods for Classifying Human Physical Activity from On-Body Accelerometers" written by Andrea Mannini and Angelo Maria Sabatini seemed to be the most useful one) and I have a somewhat clear understanding of what needs to be done (some steps might look wrong as I don't have any previous experience in statistics/ML):

1. I need to gather the accelerometer data from the smartphone along 3 axes.
2. The next step is to separate the data into AC and DC components (one of them relates to the gravitational acceleration, second one relates to body acceleration). I need to work with the body acceleration component, as this component seems to provide better results for activity recognition problems.
3. The next step is to extract some features from the body acceleration component - the features to be extracted are yet to be determined as it's not the part of the question.
4. I need to take the list of my feature vectors and train a classifier (most likely I'll go with Hidden Markov Models as this classifier seems to be the best choice for the sequential classification tasks, and the gesture recognition tasks seems to belong to sequential classification tasks).
5. After that I can evaluate and refine.

Now, there is one thing that these papers mentioned and I can not grasp yet and this thing is sliding windows. As far as I understand, I need to take the stream of the incoming accelerometer data and split it into the set of overlapping series, e.g.

`Data from 0s to 1.0s

Data from 0.5s to 1.5s

Data from 1.0s to 2.0s

...

Data from n s to (n+1.0)s`

The thing that I don't understand is that each window has number of accelerometer readings:

`x0, y0, z0

x1, y1, z1

x2, y2, z2

...

xn, yn, zn`

As you can see, this is not the vector, it's matrix. But I need a feature vector to train my classifier, so how do I squeeze the matrix into the vector?

I had some ideas on how the authors of these papers did that:

1. We can create a feature vector based on each triplet: `[featureA based on x0, y0, z0; featureB based on x0, y0, z0; featureA based on x1, y1, z1; featureB based on x1, y1, z1; ... ; featureB based on xn, yn, zn]`.
2. Or we can somehow average the accelerometer readings inside the window so that we end up having only a single triplet `xa, ya, za` ('a' for 'average') and then create a feature vector like that: `[featureA based on xa, ya, za; featureB based on xa, ya, za]`.

I don't like the second idea as it seems that averaging the accelerometer data readings, even for the small windows *might* lead to the data losses and inadequate classifier behaviour. Probably the authors of the papers meant something like the first idea, but I am not sure.

Is my understanding of how the sliding windows are created correct (that is, idea #1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are right in both part of your question but not completly.

I will say two thing:

- First, the sliding window is meant to give a context to the data at time t. Depending on the data flow, you can put the future in it or not. But the idea is indeed to put the close datas in a same window to create a new dataset where each row is a window. Having said that, extracting feature from a window is not the same as extracting feature from 3 coordinates. You could for example try to calculate the speed of mouvement (by using the previous point). So the two options are valid! you will have to get feature from single points (polar coordinates for example) but also speed, movement from last point etc etc ... Those are all good features.
- each coordinate can be a feature. You don't need to squeeze the matrix because it's not in fact any different from your first option or for that matter the second one. Your accelerometre is providing you datas from wich you can extract features to make a new data set, but you will end up with a matrix whatever you do.

Comment: Hey, Alexis! First - thanks a lot for your answer. I kind of get the idea of sliding windows now: I split the data into windows of the constant length (e.g. each window has the data for 0.1second of accelerometer stream data) and I calculate some features based on that window - e.g. what was the average speed, the value of acceleration, the value of rotation (I have access to gyroscope as well) and I turn my initial data set into the matrix where each row corresponds to a single window and each element of a row corresponds to the value of some feature in that window.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on the second part of your answer, "each coordinate can be a feature" part? Did you mean that I don't have to use sliding windows as I can calculate the features based solely on the values of the single accelerometer reading? Or you meant that I can use the x,y,z values themselves as the features, without doing any extra feature extraction steps?

Comment: you can use them as features as well. they  could be possibly important. My point was to tell you that when creating a window you will get the context of the position by looking at the past, but the present is still important and so using only the current point (x,y,z) is important too. If you want to get into this look at the Real time series feature extraction. Most of them are based on Sliding windows. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5464762/

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the help and have a great day!

Comment: always a pleasure have a great day too!